# Sonata Admin Bundle saving non-associated record

Tags: doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, symfony-2.4

I need to persist an object of non-associated entity in the postPersist callback in Sonata Admin. I am not able to get `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();` in the Sonata Admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->getModelManager()->create($object);` to persist any object in Sonata Admin Bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one too similar to **Baran** answer

```
        $query = $this->getModelManager()->createQuery('AppBundle:testEntity', 'entity');
        $results = $query->execute();
```